# Can i inject a region into a module from a host using Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, composite

I have a host thats loading a module containing 2 regions.Now in few scenarios which are available at the host end, i need to add a new region between the two in the module and load that module in the host.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i did something similiar like you. What i did was that i added all 3 regions that i needed then i used a region behaviour to collapse or show the region.

Hope this helps.